# Windows: Creating global key mapping

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, hotkeys, media-player

I'd like to create a global key mapping in Windows 10 to emulate a dedicated "next song" button (my keboard only has a play/pause button). How do I do this?

Incidentally, I'm surprised this is so difficult in Windows 10: my search turned up empty, and it's a relatively straightforward process on other operating systems. Anyone know why this might be the case, or am I just missing something?